# I'm trying to copy and paste a specific range for multiple worksheets, each with a different name, into a new workbook with defined worksheets names

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro codes which allow me to copy and paste specific range of one worksheet into a new workbook (both excel and pdf). I need to do the same but for multiple worksheets all at once. How do I modify this code.

```
Sub SaveData()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cellRange As Range

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim targetWorkbookName As String
    Dim targetWorkbookTitle As String

    Dim sourceSheetName As String
    Dim sourceRangeAddress As String
    Dim targetRangeAddress As String

    Dim rowCounter As Long


    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    sourceSheetName = "ATP620" ' Name of the source sheet
    sourceRangeAddress = "D3:AU197" ' Address of the range you want to copy in the source workbook
    targetRangeAddress = "A1" ' Cell address where you want to paste the copied range
    targetWorkbookTitle = "ATP620 WP&B 2023" ' Base file name

    ' Reference source workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    ' Create a new workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add

    ' Set reference to source range
    Set sourceRange = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sourceSheetName).Range(sourceRangeAddress)

    ' Copy the range to clipboard
    sourceRange.Copy

    ' This copies the range in the first available worksheet begining in the cell address specified
    targetWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(targetRangeAddress).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    targetWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(targetRangeAddress).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    targetWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(targetRangeAddress).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths

    Set targetRange = targetWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(targetRangeAddress).Resize(sourceRange.Rows.Count, sourceRange.Columns.Count)

    ' Adjust row heights
    For Each cellRange In sourceRange.Columns(1).Cells

        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        targetRange.Rows(rowCounter).RowHeight = cellRange.RowHeight

    Next cellRange

    ' Set the name of the new workbook
    targetWorkbookName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=targetWorkbookTitle, _
                                         fileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")

    ' Simultanously export the new workbook into pdf format and set filename the same as the new workbook
      sourceRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=targetWorkbookName, _
                                         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                         IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    If targetWorkbookName = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Saving operation canceled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Save the new workbook
    targetWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=targetWorkbookName ' Un comment this if you want it in OpenXML format: , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you identify the worksheets? All of them, the ones starting with *"ATP"*, all except *"Sheet1", "Sheet2",...* or something else?

Comment: The workbook worksheets consist of various names, e.g. ATP610, ATP610 Power, ATP620, ATP620 Power, ATP620 OS. I need to export these into two workbooks separately and the worksheets will be renamed differently. Thank you so much for your quick reply. I will test this code and report my results soon.

Comment: My apologies...How do I use both the codes in the Utilization and Method section? Do I combine the two sets of codes? Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Each post has its comment section below. These are 2 procedures where the 1st is calling the 2nd. If you run the 1st without the 2nd, VBA will 'ask' you about the 2nd. If you try to run the 2nd, it won't happen because it has arguments (`SourceWorksheet...`). In a nutshell, you copy both codes to a standard module e.g. `Module1`, and run the 1st. You can safely rename the 1st to e.g. `SaveData`. If you rename the 2nd, you need to rename its occurrence(s) in the 1st.

Comment: Ok. I've received an error message "Run-time error '424': Object required". What I did was copying the first VBA codes, followed by the second set of codes into a module. In this case, I right-click on the tab in VBE that I wanted the VBA codes to run, insert a module and then copied over the two sets of codes. Then, I amended the codes in  "Array ("Sheet1","Sheet2")" to be the name of the worksheets that I wanted to export over, i.e. "Array ("ATP610", "ATP610 Power"). I run the VBA but it was not successful. What did I miss?

Comment: Also, not to complicate my situation further, each of the tabs that I need to export has a specific range that I need to copy and paste in values and formatting. E.g. for tab ATP610, I need to copy over D3:AU197 and for tab ATP610 Power, D3:Q29. Then, I will need to group and export other tabs in a similar fashion - ATP620 and ATP620 Power, ATP621 and ATP621 Power, and so on and so forth. Will I need to copy both set of macro codes into the module of each individual tab for each separate export, i.e. ATP610 module, ATP620 module, ATP621 module, etc.?

Comment: Replace the code in `ExportDataTEST` with `Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook: Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("ATP610"): ExportData ws, "D3:AU197", " WP&D 2023": Set ws = wb.Sheets("ATP610 Power"): ExportData ws, "D3:Q29", " WP&D 2023":...etc.`. Next time add the complete information to your post. And you should comment on my post in my comment section that is below my post.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am a newbie here. I've replaced the codes under ExportDataTest with the one you've advised. The first worksheet ATP610 has been copied over to a new workbook. However, afterwards, I get the same error message "Run-time error '424': Object required" and it stopped after the first sheet was copied over to the new workbook. The second worksheet "ATP610 Power" did not get copied over to the new workbook.

Answer (score 0):

### Export a Range

**Utilization**

```
Sub ExportDataTEST()
    
    Dim Exceptions() As Variant: Exceptions = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            ExportData ws, "D3:AU197", " WP&B 2023"
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub ExportData( _
        ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SourceRangeAddress As String, _
        ByVal TargetNameSuffix As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Data"
 
    ' Reference the Source range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = SourceWorksheet.Range(SourceRangeAddress)
    
    ' Create and reference a new single-worksheet workbook, the Target workbook.
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = Application.Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
    ' Reference the Target worksheet.
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Sheets(1) ' the one and only
    
    ' Copy/paste.
    
    srg.Copy

    With tws.Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With
    
    ' Adjust the row heights.
    
    Dim sCell As Range, r As Long
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Columns(1).Cells
        r = r + 1
        tws.Rows(1).RowHeight = sCell.RowHeight
    Next sCell

    ' Get the path of the new workbook.
    
    Dim tBaseName As String: tBaseName = ws.Name & TargetNameSuffix

    Dim tPath As Variant: tPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=tBaseName, _
        FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
    
    If VarType(tPath) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Saving operation canceled", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        twb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Save the new workbook.
        
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    Dim ErrDescription As String
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        On Error Resume Next ' e.g. workbook with same name is already open
           twb.SaveAs Filename:=tPath
           ErrNum = Err.Number
           ErrDescription = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Run-time error '" & ErrNum & vbLf & vbLf & ErrDescription, _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    twb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
    
    ' Export to PDF.
    
    srg.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=tBaseName, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```